# Xcode UI Automation captureScreenWithName doesn't capture entire screen on iPhone 6 simulator and up

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am experiencing a strange problem wherein my Instruments UI Automation script written to capture screenshots in my app at various points is failing to capture the entire screen when simulated on an iPhone 6 or above, but works perfectly on the iPhone 4S, 5 and 5S simulators.

I am running the exact same script, and have tried many different variations, including adding `target.delay(1)` both before and after the calls, but it has no effect. It appears to be the `captureScreenWithName` function itself that is failing.

Here is the screen as captured on the iPhone 4S simulator:

[image]

And here is the same screen captured in the same way on the iPhone 6 simulator:

[image]

This is not the only place it is happening either. I tried it on a completely different screen and it fails to capture the entire image there as well.

It almost seems that the bigger the device size, the less that gets included in the screenshot. Could some internal process be running out of memory or failing for some other reason? Perhaps there is something in a log somewhere.

Has anyone else encountered this or have any ideas how to fix/avoid it?

Comment: We're facing the same issue, on iPhone 6 and 6+ the screens are missing items on the bottom part, using Xcode 7.1 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Debug -> Optimize Hardware for Window Scale
```

Or this:

```
CMD + 1
```

To make the Simulator full size

Comment: Disabling `Optimize Rendering for Window Scale` seems to have done it! Cheers!